# RPi 3b+ portable battery concern: enough voltage?

Tags: power-supply

For starters, I am trying to use this power pank as a portable battery for my robot:

https://www.costco.ca/PocketJuice-12%2C000-mAh-Portable-Charger-.product.100416339.html

I connected the pi to the power bank via a medium sized microUSB cable and it boots fine! However, sometimes, at irregular time intervals, I get a notification the yellow undervoltage indicator.

I think it should be fine since the pi3 requires 5V @ 2.5A and 2.4A from the powerbank should be enough since I'm not pushing the pi too hard.

Is it okay continue to power the pi with this powerbank? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how much juice does your robot need?

Comment: Is the RPi the only load powered by the power bank?